# Problem updating RCurl to source version 1.98-1.1 source in Windows 10

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I am try to update the package `RCurl` from the version `1.95-4.12` to the source version `1.98-1.1` with `R 3.6.2 (64 bits)` in `Windows 10`, but I get an error:

```
** package 'RCurl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library/RCurl'
* restoring previous 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library/RCurl'
```

Someone has any idea why this happens?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After proceeding as explained in the answer solving the question in https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-shlib-internal-args-c-14-standard-requested-but-cxx14-is-not-defined/16819 I could install `RCurl 1.98-1.1` without problems